# How do you remove the x-axis from a bar chart produced by Google's Visualization API?

Tags: javascript, css, charts, google-visualization

Referring to the kind of chart shown here:
http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/barchart.html

There doesn't seem to be a simple switch, and changing the axis color to white (on a white background) didn't seem to do anything. I even tried jquery to hide the selectors produced by the api output but no dice.

Answer (score 87):

You can set `hAxis.textPosition` to the value of '`none`'

For example:

```
var options = {

                hAxis: { textPosition: 'none' },
            };

chart.draw(data, options);
```

See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Configuration_Options

Comment: if i want to remove y axis with label. what to do?

Comment: @InnovativeThinker hAxis stands for, "horizontal Axis", so to change the other you would use, vAxis, as in, "vertical Axis"

Comment: this removes the text yet does not reclaim the space used prior. There is additional padding on the left side

Comment: Do you know how to show some values ​​on the X axis? but when I click on the point I see the value x, y (the problem is that I have more than 300 points and it is not readable).

Answer (score 4):

I was able to remove the label in the material version of the chart by removing the string in my datatable.

Before:

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
```

After:

```
data.addColumn('string', '');
```

Answer (score 4):

`let options = {legend: { position: 'none' }};`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: This is the only answer that is working as of today.

Answer (score 3):

Their API has no function for this indeed, but:

```
chart.draw( data, 
    {
        width: 400, 
        height: 240, 
        is3D: true, 
        legend :'none',
        axisFontSize : 0
    });
```

Setting axisFontSize to 0 will remove your x-axis data. :)

Answer (score 2):

Google changes the API so fast, this is what works today:

```
chart.draw(daily, {
    hAxis : {textColor: '#ffffff'},
    [... your other options here ...]
});
```

Comment: Do you know how I can change the cursor to a hand when I hover on hAxis?

Comment: This is a terrible solution. It depends on you haveing a white background, and will probably fail if the user drags the cursor over the area of the text.

Answer (score 1):

axisFontSize : 0 will remove x-axis and y-axis data

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html#axis_label_styles

Axis Label Styles chxs "axis_or_tick"

You'll notice this documentation: "_ - (Underscore) Draw neither axis line nor tick marks. If you want to hide an axis line, use this value."

Example: 'chxs=0,,0,0,_'

Answer (score 0):

Use this to remove axis from chart

```
hAxis: { textPosition: "none", gridlines: { count: 0 } },
  vAxis: { textPosition: "none", gridlines: { count: 0 } },
  baselineColor:"transparent",
```