# How to hide column label on google chart

Tags: css, charts

I want to hide all column labels on google chart same as the image bellow.
[image]

Can anyone help me ?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its Already Explained in this URL :: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14751106/4119740

Please Go Through it .

If You Want to hide then you can using options from :: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Configuration_Options

Example

```
var options = {
          hAxis: { textPosition: 'none' }
        };
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('yourID'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This option work for me

```
hAxis: { textStyle:{color: 'snow'}}
```