# How to hide the percentage legends in google bar chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using google bar chart in my website, i want to hide the percentage legends but can't find the settings that can do that.

Here is my chart and the settings

[image]

```
optionsBar = {
            height      : 95,
            legend      : { position: 'none' },
            bar         : { groupWidth: '60%' },
            isStacked   : 'percent',
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            chartArea   : { left: 0, width: '100%'  },
            hAxis       : { baselineColor: 'none', gridlines: { color: 'none' } }
        };
```

Comment: I have found a solution, just set `height = 70`, thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is set `height = 70`, the legends will be hidden because the chart will be lower and there is no place to display the legends.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to hide the x values.
I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14751106/4561535) , which says use:

```
hAxis: { textPosition: 'none' }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it's not working, I have found a solution.

Comment: please post your solution