# Google Chart JS Option to remove Bottom Legend

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am working on a JSON based Line chart using the Google Charts Library, however I would like to remove the bottom legend (by still preserving the left one) but I am unable to get that to work.

[image]

Here my current and working code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "prices.json",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false
    }).responseJSON;
    var key = "prices";
    var ar = Object.entries(jsonData["prices"]).map(([a, b]) => [new Date(b[0]).toLocaleDateString("en-US"), b[1]]);
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'value');
    data.addRows(ar);
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      title: 'International Wine Sales',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      colors: ['#00d1b2'],
      format: 'none',
      legend: 'none',
      textPosition: 'none'
    });
  }
</script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
```

JSON data:

```
  {
     "prices": [
     [
        1660694400000,
        1.3773296984378443
     ],
     [
        1660780800000,
        1.4831769984789143
     ],
     [
        1660867200000,
        1.4806663666679991
     ],
     [
        1660897499000,
        1.3085747624144402
     ]
     ]
  }
```

Until here all fine, the above code works and is well functioning, however the bottom legend is still visible even though I've added **legend: 'none', textPosition: 'none'**

I've seen people suggesting to change the actual text color to white, however that's not an ideal solution for me. Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14751106/519413

Comment: Also, for future reference, I've seen on your last couple of questions that your code is not well formatted. You should look to do this as it will make your code easier and quicker for yourself and others to read.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I managed to fix it now by applying the options as var options as compared to what I previously had, so thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. Could you please provide some more info about my formatting - would absolutely love to learn more and make things easier in case I am seeking for help. Thank you

Comment: Glad you got your issue resolved. Regarding the formatting - you can see how I've amended the code in your question. I'd suggest using an IDE which does this for you, as it saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by using the following method in my existing code:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
     function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
     url: "prices.json",
     dataType: "json",
     async: false
  }).responseJSON;
  var key = "prices";
  var options = {
     title: 'International Wine Sales',
     backgroundColor: 'transparent',
     colors: ['#00d1b2'], format: 'none',
     legend: 'none',
     textPosition: 'none',
     hAxis: { textPosition: 'none' },
  };
  var ar = Object.entries(jsonData["prices"]).map(([a, b]) => [new Date(b[0]).toLocaleDateString("en-US"), b[1]]);
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'value');
  data.addRows(ar);
  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
  }
  </script>
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
```